# Protect intellectual property in autodesk viewer js library?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an app that I'm building that utilizes the Autodesk viewer javascript library/API. If I upload a series of .iam & .ipt files for a product, and what to share it with some clients, but I don't want to give away intellectual property, such as being able to use the measure tool, or not being able to select certain sub-parts.

I know you can disable certain toolbars (which can be undone in the js console) or remove them entirely via headless mode, but considering the browser has to access to the access token, a clever person could use that token with the proper URN, and get full access to the data. Correct?

So is there a recommended way to protect our models so that viewers of it cannot take our intellectual property??

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove the attach surface with the info available to the browser agent is proxying - see [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy) for details. Basically you are redirecting Viewer to access our endpoints via your own proxy service where the access token can be assigned implicitly, eliminating the need to expose access tokens to browser agents directly:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.setApiEndpoint('https://yourproxyurl')
```

W/o the access token, having access to only the Object IDs/URNs of your models would be futile as all our endpoints to retrieve model data are secured by requiring a valid access token with sufficient token scopes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very helpful. That helps to obscure the access token, which is good. But a person could still load the non-headless version, and be able to measure parts and steal intellectual property. Correct? Furthermore, even if you could not allow measuring, some companies won’t want to show all the plate individual part details in weldments, as that would be a breach of intellectual property. I think.

Comment: Then why not even proxy the Viewer.js and its dependencies themselves and physically block the load of measure tools(`./extensions/Measure/Measure.js`) to further stretch the attack vector? As for sensitive parts simply hide them by their dbids and block(piggyback or remove completely) `viewer.showAll` - an attacker would need to figure out the association of dbids to the parts and that'd take a fair amount of work w/o direct access to both the model data and Forge APIs.

Comment: great, where is the source to Viewer.js? I can't seem to find it on github.

Comment: It's not entirely open sourced and you will need to make do with your browser's dev tools and source maps for tracing purposes.